convert existing oracle table timestamp value from AEST to UTC
I need database sql query to convert from AEST to UTC.
15/MAR/24 05:23:17.148565000 AM should update to 14/MAR/24 19:23:17.148565000 PM
I tried TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ but this is not working as the input date fromat is not accepted

What is the datatype of the column you're trying to convert ? Pls share the code you were executing when you got "as the input date fromat is not accepted"

TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ converts a string to a timestamp; if you already have a timestamp then that is not the right function to use. But exactly what you need to do depends on the current data type - is it a timestamp or timestamp with time zone or timestamp with local time zone...?

What is timezone AEST? To get available timezone have a look at SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES

@WernfriedDomscheit In March 2024 there was only one Australian Territory using AEST, Queensland, the others that use AEST only use it from April - October and would be using AEDT on that date.

If your column has a TIMESTAMP data type:
CREATE TABLE table_name (ts TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO table_name (ts) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2024-03-15 05:23:17.148565000');

Then you can convert it to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data-type using FROM_TZ and then use AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' to convert it to a UTC time zone:
SELECT ts AS aest_ts,
       FROM_TZ(ts, 'Australia/Queensland') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_ts
FROM   table_name;

Which outputs:



AEST_TS
UTC_TS




2024-03-15 05:23:17.148565
2024-03-14 19:23:17.148565 UTC



If you want to UPDATE the table to be in the UTC time zone then use the same conversion as in the SELECT statement:
UPDATE table_name 
SET ts = FROM_TZ(ts, 'Australia/Queensland') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';


If your column has a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type:
CREATE TABLE table_name (ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
INSERT INTO table_name (ts)
  VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2024-03-15 05:23:17.148565000 Australia/Queensland');

Then the initial conversion is not necessary and you can just use AT TIME ZONE 'UTC':
SELECT ts AS aest_ts,
       ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_ts
FROM   table_name;

Which outputs:



AEST_TS
UTC_TS




2024-03-15 05:23:17.148565 AUSTRALIA/QUEENSLAND
2024-03-14 19:23:17.148565 UTC



Again, if you want to UPDATE the table then you can use the same conversion as in the SELECT query in the UPDATE:
UPDATE table_name 
SET ts = ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';


If your column has the data-type TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE then use exactly the same conversion as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE:
SELECT ts AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Queensland' AS aest_ts,
       ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_ts
FROM   table_name;

Which outputs the same as for the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE example.
Using an UPDATE on a TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE to try to change the time zone is pointless as the database will just convert it to back to the local time zone when storing the data. If you are using this data type then, if you want it in a specific time zone, you will need to specify the time zone when you display the data (and not when you store the data).
fiddle
